# How to create a centered header for a table that spans all the columns?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have a table

[image]

I want to create a header "a list of numbers"

[image]

But my code, only allows me to put this sentence in one of the columns, resulting in

[image]

How do I fix this behavior? Put a sentence that spans the columns?

My code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \hline \\
 & & \\
  \hline\\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `\multicolumn` command for this.

Comment: @I needed to use \table* because I wanted to use a double column. Can I put a multi-column inside of \table*?

Comment: Do you want the text "A list of Numbers"  to be wider than the table's horizontal lines (as shown in the second image) or do you want the text to stay inside there lines? If the latter is the case, would you want to split the text into two lines or should the table be widened accordingly? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriss No need to be wider. This is just a small example. My actual table is wide enough that any header will be contained within the horizontal lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` for this purpose. Depending on the actual length of the text and the width of the table, you might have to do some manual adjustments. As long as the text is shorter than the width of the table, the following simple approach will work. In the following MWE, I have added a second variant of your table in which I have replaced the `\hline`s  with the horizontal  lines from the `booktabs` package. These lines have some vertical white space around them which improves the spacing around them:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} \\
  \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \toprule
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{text} \\
  \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blabla}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you just have a bunch of these code lying around and can use them to answer whatever question that comes up?